# post_parent don't work and return 0 page

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to resume pages on WordPress that have a specific page as the parent page.

Why is this not working? This is my args code for loop:

```
$args=array(
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'orderby'           => 'publish_date',
    'post_parent'       => 98727,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to set the post type which defaults to `post`, so try adding `'post_type' => 'page'` to your args? Or change the `page` to whatever the actual post type slug.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I had forgotten about this!